# Angular 17 Google Auth Problem. How to resolve [ERROR] TS2304: Cannot find name 'google' in Angular 17?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-api, google-oauth, angular17

I am trying to implement Google Auth in Angular(+Express) app with Google Identity Services library. It seems to me I have done everything according to Google tutorial. But "[ERROR] TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'" occured.

I have added  `<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>` to index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Render</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

and try

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../_interfaces/user';

const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
   }),
};

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
   private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(this.getData);
   loggedInUser: Observable<User | null>; //

   client: any;
   access_token: any;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
      this.loggedInUser = this.userSubject.asObservable();
      this.init();
   }
  
   init() {
      this.client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
         client_id: '***********',
         scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
         callback: (tokenResponse: { access_token: any }) => {
            this.access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
         },
      });
   }
```

but have: [ERROR] TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'. [plugin angular-compiler]

Can you help me?

Comment: Run `npm i -D @types/google.accounts` - Then in `tsconfig.app.json` add `google.accounts` to the `compilerOptions:types` field

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.accounts/index.d.ts) the declaration file

Comment: I've installed  `npm i -D @types/google.accounts` and added `google.accounts` to the `compilerOptions:types`: `"compilerOptions": {
     ...
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "module": "ES2022",
      "useDefineForClassFields": false,
      "types": ["node", "google.accounts"],
      "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
   }`  but error is the same: `[ERROR] TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'. [plugin angular-compiler]`

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when Typescript can't identify the type definitions for the Google identity service library. you can follow the following steps to solve this.

- check whether the types array of `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json` file contain the type `google.identity.oauth2`.

`tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": ["google.identity.oauth2"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

- install type definitions of Google identity service with `npm install --save-dev @types/google.identity.oauth2`

Comment: After `npm install --save-dev @types/google.identity.oauth2` I've got `npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fgoogle.identity.oauth2 - Not found`

Comment: try this npm install google-auth-library